# Several Discrete Logarithm Zero Knowledge Proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm, fiat-shamir

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_heuristic) there is an approach for proving knowledge of $x$ such that $g^x = y$. How can I prove that I know $x_1, x_2$ such that $g^{x_1} = y_1, g^{x_2}=y_2$. Of course, I can make these proofs separately but I would like to combine them into a single one. My idea is to prove that I know such $x = x_1 + x_2$ that $g^x = y_1 y_2$. But is it safe? Does not it make the system vulnerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is it safe?

Well, knowledge of $x_1 + x_2$ does not imply that you know either $x_1$ or $x_2$.

On the other hand, if you were to prove knowledge of $r_1x_1 + r_2x_2$, for a random (e.g. selected by the verifier or a Random Oracle) $r_1, r_2$ values, that would be a zero knowledge proof of knowledge of both $x_1, x_2$

This can be done by extending the single-exponent zero knowledge proof in a fairly simple way:

- Prover sends $g^v$ to the verifier (for some random $v$)
- Verifier sends random $c, d$ to the prover
- Prover sends $r = v - cx_1 - dx_2$ to verifier
- Verifier accepts if $g^v = g^r (g^{x_1})^c (g^{x_2})^d$

Comment: Can $c$ and $d$ be generated via a hash function?

Comment: @КириллВолков: yes; for my example, I did the interactive version - it's straight-forward to turn it into a noninteractive protocol

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: Can I extend the algorithm for $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n$ in the same way?

Comment: @КириллВолков: yes, it works in the obvious way.

Comment: Maybe you know, where I can find the proof of the proposed scheme?